# git diff is not showing all changes

Tags: git, github

I have a file called `app.js`. I added lines 131-136, deleted lines 83-84 and added lines 88-91. When I type `git status`, it shows that `app.js` has changed. When I type `git diff` it only shows the added lines 131-136 and deleted lines 83-84. It does not show added lines 88-91. Any idea why? I opened up the actual repository on github.com and lines 88-91 are not there there. (I saw this issue earlier too but ignored it thinking it was a one time thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` default behavior is to display the diff between the *index* and the content on disk.

You can view what is in the index using `git diff --cached`,
you can view the diff wrt your last commit using `git diff HEAD`

---

Is it possible that you executed `git add` when app.js contained the new lines 88-91, and that you added the two other modifications afterwards ?

In that case : `git diff` will only show you the extra modifications ; use `git diff HEAD` to view your complete diff

Comment: To add a bit to this answer: user2719875 might not realize that there are *three* active copies of `app.js`. One is in the current commit: `git show HEAD:app.js`. One is in the work-tree, as an ordinary file named `app.js`. The *middle* one, between the other two, is in the index / staging-area: `git show :app.js`. `git diff` compares two of the three; you choose *which* two. `git status` compares *all three*, starting with `HEAD:app.js` vs `:app.js`, then separately, `:app.js` vs `app.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Scroll down and see the rest of the changes by pressing `return` / `enter` in the keyboard.

`git diff`

opens up the changes in (usually, `less`) so press `return` to see all changes. press `q` to quit.

Comment: `git diff` opens up the changes in a pager which is seldom `vi/vim`. Usually it's `less`. You cannot exit `vi(m)` by pressing `q` but you can exit `less` this way.